# How to Call the class that extends RelativeLayout programatically in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've made a layout in java class by extending the `RelativeLayout` and want to call this view programatically when the button is clicked. I was able to set the custom layout in the xml file like this

```
<com.sample.CustomLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I have set some sample of the code below

```
public class Card extends RelativeLayout {

    TextView tutorialok;

    public Card(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Card(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
}
```

How will I call the this class when the button is clicked ?
Since, I'm new to Android, some tips or code will be helpful !

Comment: Call this class to do what? A layout is a container to lay widgets out on screen so they make sense to be used when you're setting up your screen not on a button click. Do you mean to open a new activity based on this custom layout?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. What I want to do is to show the class that extends the RelativeLayout like a popup dialog box when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
//custom layout is called by fully Qualified name ... package.classname
<com.sample.card
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I've intentionally wrote a dummy package name for example. And  what I want to do is show the <com.sample.card../> programatically when the user clicks the button. I do not want to declare it in the xml script.

Comment: use View's Visible, INVISIBLE feature for that